# Forward locking a downloaded file

Tags: android

I am interested in forward locking a downloaded file (an image, or a video, etc.). Is there any way to do this?

As far as I can tell packages can be forward locked, but their resources remain public. Is there a way to forward lock a specific file I've downloaded to the Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends.

In order to do that, you need to use a **DRM forward lock**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_DRM

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091231141343AAx7cVS

But doing so isn't quite simple.

Also, if you are an app developer you can download files to a private folder. This should be reasonably safe but I think that people with rooted devices could see the files if they wanted to. Also, be sure to use a secure connection (https) otherwise people could intercept the traffic and reconstruct the file! DRM already addresses this issue.

Comment: i don't know more about forward lock.is it available in android?then how can i use it?

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html and see if there's anything useful.

Comment: thanks for your help.do you have any code drop for forward lock using android drm.

Comment: sorry, but no... I think that most of the times you should implement this mechanism in server-side and then compatible devices should know how to read the files.